# While Loop in python GUI with tkinter ( blocking password after a few attempts )

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, while-loop

Hope you're having a great day.
I created an Input Password interface. After inputting the correct password it should be showing access granted in a Label, which works fine with my code. However, in case of an incorrect password, I want to include only 3 attempts. If you input an incorrect password 1st & the 2nd time, it should be showing "incorrect password". After final attempts, it should be showing "account blocked". The problem is when it comes to incorrect passwords & 1st attempt, It straight up shows that "account blocked"
Here is what I've got so far,

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

# Creating Button Command
def password():
    correct_password = "123"
    enter_the_password = pass_entry.get()
    number_of_try=0
    number_of_max_try=3
    max_try=""

    while enter_the_password!=correct_password and max_try!="reached":
        if number_of_try<number_of_max_try:
            enter_the_password
            number_of_try=number_of_try+1
            if enter_the_password!=correct_password:
                response= "Incorrect Password"
        else:
            max_try="reached"

    if max_try=="reached":
        response= "Too many attempts. Account blocked"
    else:
        response= "Access Granted"
    
    pass_label.config(text=response)
    pass_entry.delete(0, END)
    
# Creating widget 
pass_entry=Entry(root, width=30)
pass_entry.pack(pady=5)
done_button= Button(root, text="Press", command=password).pack(pady=10)

pass_label= Label(root, width=30)
pass_label.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should not use while loop inside `password()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop immediately re-enters without letting the user type another password. In fact you do not need that loop because `root.mainloop()` already provides it.

Instead, you should remove your `while` loop, and initialize your variables outside your function `password`. Every time the `done_button` is pressed, the function `password` should check the password only once.